# Python: Compare Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a single dictionary that has two keys identifying a set of data. The keys are currently stored as permutations (so key 1,2 exists and key 2,1 exists, even though they have the same data).

I'd like to eliminate the repeated values.

For example:

I have this (where key1, key2 is repeated as key2, key1)

```
dict = {'key1, key2':1, 'key2, key3':2, 'key2, key1':1}
```

I'd like to have

```
dict = {'key1, key2':1,'key2, key3':2}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: make the keys `frozenset`s instead.

Comment: `frozenset`s would probably be the most efficient choice, as roippi wrote. Sorted tuples will work too and might be more convenient in some use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never use `dict` as a variable name, it will shadow the builtin.

You can use any immutable object as a dictionary key, so perhaps a collection like `frozenset` is more suited for your use case than strings:

```
>>> data = {'key1, key2':1, 'key2, key3':2, 'key2, key1':1}
>>> new_data = {
  frozenset(item.strip() for item in key.split(',')): val 
  for key, val in data.items()
}
>>> new_data

{frozenset({'key1', 'key2'}): 1, 
 frozenset({'key2', 'key3'}): 2}
```

If you really need the keys to be strings:

```
>>> {", ".join(key): val for key, val in new_data.items()}

{'key2, key1': 1, 'key3, key2': 2}
```

[update]

Using sorted tuples as suggested by Achim:

```
>>> new_data = {
  tuple(sorted(item.strip() for item in key.split(','))): val
  for key, val in data.items()
}
>>> new_data

{('key1', 'key2'): 1, ('key2', 'key3'): 2}

>>> {", ".join(key): val for key, val in new_data.items()}

{'key1, key2': 1, 'key2, key3': 2}
```

Comment: I'm really new to python, so bear with me here.

I tried to apply your code in block 1, but I received this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Nevermind, I got the frozensets to work. However, I'm not sure how to compare them now?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Dictionary keys are guaranteed to be unique, so you don't need to compare anything when building your dictionary. If you want to test for presence use the `in` operator (`key in my_dict` will be true if the key exists).

Comment: The file that I'm importing will use two keys to identify one object. So [1,2]:a,b. But there are some entries that swap the keys, so [2,1]:a,b. If I convert everything to frozen sets, then I should have two frozensets [1,2] and [2,1] that are the same in my dictionary, right? Or would converting them to frozensets eliminate one of the entries?

Comment: No, order doesn't matter for Python `sets` (we use `frozenset` because plain `set` is mutable and dictionary keys must be immutable). If order matters to you, use sorted tuples, if not you can use frozensets. Both solutions will not duplicate your composite keys no matter the original order.

Answer (score 2):

Does `dict((", ".join(sorted(k.split(", "))), v) for k, v in d.iteritems())` do what you're looking for?